# Spectrum of isometry not in circle

Tags: functional-calculus

I have a reasoning that is wrong but I don't understand why.

Suppose we have a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ and $v \in A$ is a proper isometry, so $v^*v = 1$ but $v v^* \neq 1$.
Take the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}: y \mapsto \overline{y}y$.
Then by functional calculus the $f(v) = v^* v = 1$.
This means that by the spectral mapping theorem we get $\sigma(f(v)) = \sigma(1) = 1$ and $1 = \sigma(f(v)) = f(\sigma(v))$.
This shows that for every element in the spectrum of $v$ we have
$$ \forall y \in \sigma(v): f(y) \in f(\sigma(v)) = 1, $$
so $\forall y \in \sigma(v): |y| = 1$.
This shows that $\sigma(v)$ is a subset of the circle.

Of course, this calculation is wrong, because this would show that every isometry is a unitary.
However, I can't seem to find the mistake.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The isometry is not a normal element, hence functional calculus does not apply.

Comment: Can you tell us the space on which your isometry $v$ is defined? And also what a proper isometry is.

Comment: The space is a unital $C^*$-algebra and the definition of proper isometry is next to it, it means that it is an isometry but not a unitary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because a proper isometry is not a normal element, so functional calculus is not applicable.